# Reportlab, table too large and LayoutError

Tags: python, reportlab

I am creating a report using ReportLab.

I have to present a table which does not fit inside a single page.

In my original code I had this:

```
def build_table(data):

    data = format_data(data)
    table = Table(data, repeatRows=1, style=settings.report.tablestyle)
    return table
```

This will produce:

```
reportlab.platypus.doctemplate.LayoutError: Flowable <Caption at 0x8d2ba58>...(294.02734375 x 623) too large on page 6 in frame None(699.4960629921259 x 461.3858267716535*) of template 'Normal'
```

The solution from another post here suggested to use `LongTable` instead of `Table`, so I did:

```
def build_table(data):

    data = format_data(data)
    #table = Table(data, repeatRows=1, style=settings.report.tablestyle)
    table = LongTable(data, repeatRows=1)
    table.setStyle(settings.report.tablestyle)
    return table
```

However I am getting the same error.

Any other solution to this?

***EDIT:***

from my `class report`  inside `settings` I have:

```
tablestyle = TableStyle([('ROWBACKGROUNDS', (0, 0), (-1, -1), [white, Color(.9, .9, .9)]),
                             ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (0, -1), 3),
                             ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 3),
                             ('TOPPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                             ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                             ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE'),
                             ('SIZE', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 7),
                             ('SIZE', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 8),
                             ('FACE', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'calibrib'),
                             ('FACE', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 'calibri'),
                             ])
```

Comment: What are the settings in settings.report.tablestyle?

Comment: Hi mauve, I didn't know that was important, but of course I will edit my question with it.

Comment: I'm wondering if the padding settings are tripping you up - did you notice that the leftpadding is from (0,0) to (0,-1) when all the rest are (0,0) to (-1,-1)?.

Comment: I see it I didn't see that before, but my question would be then what has this to do with the table being too long for the page??, is not about how wide it is , is about how long it is. Im curious to know

Comment: It says "too large", not specifically "too long" or "too wide". I've used "Table" as a flowable to frame up to 7 pages worth of pictures in a report and I haven't had this problem (all in the same table), and when I specified pictures that were too wide, it just printed them off the page. It's why I suspected something in the TableStyle. Did that fix it?

Comment: No, it did not solve the issue.